# Asymptotic pseudo orbit of an action

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-dynamics

Let $G$ be finitely generated group (i.e $G= <S>$  $S=\{ s_1, ...,
s_n\}$) and  $\varphi:G\times M\longrightarrow M$ is an action then
$f:G\longrightarrow M$ is called $\delta$- pseudo orbit if $d(f(sg),
\varphi(s,f(g)))<\delta$ for every $s\in S$, $g\in G$. How can we
define asymptotic pseudo orbit for action $\varphi:G\times
M\longrightarrow M$?

Comment: Is $M$ a Riemannian manifold or something of this sort? It might help to add some details, as well as some context for your question.

Comment: Is there an existing definition of an asymptotic pseudo-orbit for a $\mathbb{Z}$-action? If so, what is it?

Comment: Let $M$ be a compact manifold, In $(M, g)$,  $\{x_n\}\subseteq M$ is
an asymptotic pseudo orbit if $d(g(x_n), x_{n+1})\longrightarrow 0$
as $|n|\longrightarrow \infty$.